# Open pdf file from server location in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

We have a requirement where I need to open the pdf file from particular location in server i.e. "C:\PdfFile\Test.pdf".

I have tried this solution:

```
            string fileName = lnk.CommandArgument.ToString();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo a = new    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(fileName, "Open");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(a);
```

This is working for local as we have same path in our local But this is not working when we host the site.

Comment: OK what happened when you open the PDF on the server? Who will look at it?

Comment: It's open in server but i have requirement to open it locally.

Comment: But the app that has the code is hosted on the server.... a website. Not on the client. So how you expect your code to make sense based on your required?

Comment: that's what i need. I need to open the pdf file from in local environment not in server.

Answer (score 3):

In you ASP.NET form application you have to add this code:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyFile.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(@"C:\PdfFile\Test.pdf"));
Response.End();
```